# Referencing file from within the same JAR file as the application

Tags: java, reference, jar, internal

I have a Java application in Eclipse that references .XML files as templates for other functionality. Usually I package the .JAR file without these files, because placing them within the same folder as the .JAR file seems to work fine with this reference:

```
File myFile = new File("templates/templateA.xsd");
```

I now require that these templates be placed within the same .JAR file as this application. I can include them with no problems, but these references no longer seem to work.

Is there a correct way of referencing the .XML file from within the same .JAR that the application is running from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to read this file, you might not need a java.io.File but just an InputStream that you can get via

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("templates/templateA.xsd")
```

If you really need a java.io.File... I do not know... The last time a really needed a File, I just copied the InputStream to a temporary file but this is ugly.

Comment: I have the same problem here that I mentioned in the comment above. With my current hierarchy of files, I always end up with a null input stream.

Comment: This is because the path is relative to the .java on which to do '.getClass()' in 'this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("templates/templateA.xsd")'.
You can try to use System class for that : 'System.getClass().getResourceAsStream("templates/templateA.xsd")' or simply put the resource file in the same directory as the java class using it and use 'this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("templateA.xsd")'.

Comment: Using System gives me an error about making a static reference from the non-static method getClass(). Moving the files unfortunately isn't really an option.

Comment: for System class, access it by this way : System.class.getResourceAsStream("").

Comment: Thanks. I did: InputStream inputStream = System.class.getResourceAsStream(filename);

System.out.println(inputStream);

It is still printing null :(

Comment: Try putting a '/' at the beginning of your path. System.class.getResourceAsStream("/templates/templateA.xsd").

Comment: That removed the error but it seems that any combination of getResourceAsStream is returning null.

Comment: Is 'templates' directory in your classpath?

Comment: Managed to get it working after relocating the templates to the resources folder :) thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to know how to load the files from class path.
one of the ways is as follows

```
class XMLLoader {

    public String loadXML(String fileName){
         InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
    // do the loading of the file from the given input stream.
   }
```

}

you know that the "templates" folder should be inside of your jar.

Comment: I've seen this implementation used before, but whenever I try it I end up with a null input stream. I have a separate class called XML Loader using this code. That means the Class is of course located in in the src folder. The xml files I need are before the source folder, at the root called Templates.